# Две ОС подтормаживают

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-10

Решил установить 16-ую Ubuntu что называется рядом с Windows 10.
До этого сжал том до 50 гб и собственно, выделил 8 гб для раздела подкачки в ОС Ubuntu.
Но теперь у меня очень медленно загружается сама винда, после перезагрузки.
Если раньше запускалась за секунды 4-5 то сейчас в минуту может доходить. И да не так долго, но всё познаётся в сравнении как говорится. Хотел сделать дефрагментацию, но вроде она и так автоматом раскидывает ресурсы.
Подскажите как можно подправить работу ОСистем?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего проблема в том, что после сжатия на загрузочном томе Windows осталось мало места. Это особенность файловой системы NTFS - если объём свободного пространства тома менее 12% от его полного объёма, то это приводит к фрагментации MFT, что катастрофически сказывается на производительности дисковой подсистемы.

Рекомендую увеличить загрузочный том так, чтобы минимум четверть его была свободна, и выполнить дефрагментацию служебных файлов файловой системы (MFT и пр.) - причём штатный дефрагментатор этого делать не умеет, используйте сторонние программные средства. И всегда следите за тем, чтобы на этом (как, впрочем, и на других) томе было достаточно свободного пространства.

Comment: Дело в том, что я выделил память из жесткого диска. А диск который с виндой более сжать еще больше просто некуда, он изначально 1тб разделил поровну - один под системный C другой под жесткий.
Соответственно там гуляет 200+ гб(что в C, что в D).

Но диск который я отдельно выделил для ubuntu - уже занят на 70%. Возможно стоит его увеличить?

Comment: Нет, я честно прочитал. Несколько раз. И всё одно мало что понял.